# Wrap all text outside tags in another tag

Tags: javascript, regex, positive-lookahead

My html can look (and sometimes looks) like this:

```
<p>Some text <b>some <i>more text</i></b></p>a little bit more text
```

I need to wrap in spans every word within these tags. So the wrapped words would be Some, text, some, more, text, a, little, bit, more, text. I tried to use this code:

```
html_variable.replace(/(?<=>)[^<>]+(?=<)/g,filter)
```

where filter is a custom function, using which I easily wrapped every word. However, it turned out that (?<=>), a positive lookbehind, is not yet supported in ios. I am really bad in regular expressions, so I am asking for your help. Is there any well-supported alternative to the code above?

Comment: [Obligatory reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1715579)

Comment: Javascript/Jquery will do too.

Comment: `some` and `text` should be wrapped together? Or separated?

Comment: In the end I want the very same html but with every single word in a span.

Comment: @miha64 Lookbehind is not officially supported. The fact that Chrome supports it does not make it supported elsewhere :). Anyways, It is part of the ECMAScript 2020 language, so in the end It will be supported at some point by all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
\w+(?![^<>]*>)
```

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Al4JvF/2/)

This *may* work for you, depending in your input. There are plenty of cases that will make this fail replacing content you don't want to replace (for example content of `script` and `title` tags)

Anyways, for a throw-away job and a limited input, [It may work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/7500028).

Comment: Only need to check for > once, I believe: `\w+(?![^<]*>)`